# How to add label on SVG circle in d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a function that creates circle of given parameters, but I want to add label to it whenever a button has been pressed.

```
function createCircle(cx, cy, radius, color){
// create circle with the given parameters
 var circle =  canvas.append("circle")
    .attr("cx", cx)
    .attr("cy", cy)
    .attr("r", radius)
    .attr("fill", color)
    .text("Hello");
return circle;
}
```

I have another function that creates a line on button click

```
function createLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, color){
var line = canvas.append("line")
    .attr("x1", x1)
    .attr("y1", y1)
    .attr("x2", x2)
    .attr("y2", y2)
    .attr("stroke", color)
    .attr("stroke-width", 1);
return line;
```

}

I want to add label to the circle after the button has been pressed. Is there any way to do it.

Comment: How does the second part relate to your question. Do you want to draw the text on the circle or on top of the line. ?

Comment: An **circle** node can NOT accommodate **text** node. You can create a **text** node somewhere around that **circle** node, or given a **g** node to accommodate **circle** and **text**. You would better to learn some SVG syntax before diving into d3js.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the code below.

I have added an attribute data-id to the circle and bound a function to the click event. That function looks up the event with d3.event gets its target, creates a selection from it and extracts the id.

Then it's just a matter of creating a new selection with the label and animating it.

Hope it helps!

```js
let svg = d3.select("#my-svg");
let data = [
  {
    key: "01",
    x: 50,
    y: 60,
    r: 40,
    color: "red",
    label: "Hello world!"
  }
];
let handleClick = (d, i) => {
  let target = d3.select(event.target);
  let id = target.attr("data-id")
  let text = d3.select(`#label-${id}`);
    text.transition()
    .duration(500)
    .attr("opacity", text.attr("opacity") === "0" ? 1 : 0)
};
svg
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("id", d => `circle-${d.key}`)
  .attr("data-id", d => d.key)
  .attr("cx", d => d.x)
  .attr("cy", d => d.y)
  .attr("r", d => d.r)
  .attr("fill", d => d.color)
  .on("click", handleClick);
svg
  .selectAll("text")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("text")
  .style("pointer-events", "none")
  .attr("id", d => `label-${d.key}`)
  .attr("x", d => d.x)
  .attr("y", d => d.y)
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("fill", "#000")
  .attr("opacity", 0)
  .text(d => d.label);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Label on click</title>
</head>
<body>
  <svg id="my-svg" width="100" height="100"></svg>
</body>
</html>
```